# Discord Bot not responding

Tags: python, python-3.5, discord, discord.py

So I am messing around with writing a discord bot. I know python, but I haven't messed around with it in awhile. Anyways I am trying to setup a bot just to expand my code knowledge.

Right now I am simply trying to get it to respond to !ping. When I send the !ping message in my discord, the bot doesn't respond. Below is a snippet of the code. Script launches with no issues in IDLE.

```py3
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!ping'):
            userID = message.author.id
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))
```

Comment: `client.event` should be `@client.event`, because it is a decorator.

Comment: I can't believe I freaking missed that.... Thank  you for fixing my stupiditiy.

Answer (score 0):

try this to send the message :

```
await message.send(f"{message.author.name} pong!")
```